# alert cheked checkbox por nombre o clase

Tags: jquery

Necesito mostrar un alert cuando un checkbox sea chekeado por medio de la clase o nombre , he intentado hacer lo siguiente sin resultados gracias.

```js
$('input[name="name_vh"]').on('click', function(){
  alert("chekeado");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="class_vh" name="name_vh" type="checkbox">
<input class="class_vh" name="name_vh" type="checkbox">
<input class="class_vh" name="name_vh" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Tienes mal el nombre, debe ser `name_vh` no `class_vh`

Comment: Aún así funciona mal @Lixus. Lanza el alert **siempre**, cuando se chequea y cuando se deja de chequear,  porque lo está ligando al evento `click`. Funciona ligándolo al evento `change` como he mostrado en mi respuesta.

Comment: Puede ser tanto change como click, con que esté la validación de `this.checked`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes ligarlo al evento `change` y lanzar el alert cuando `this.checked` sea verdadero, del siguiente modo:

```js
$(".class_vh").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
    alert("chequeado");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="class_vh" name="name_vh" type="checkbox">
<input class="class_vh" name="name_vh" type="checkbox">
<input class="class_vh" name="name_vh" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Su problema no era tener mal el selector, o el acercamiento a la solución, sino que puso mal el nombre, y puso el nombre de la clase en ves de este